# run a meteor app with forever-monitor

Tags: meteor, forever

i want to start a bundled meteor app from a other meteor app, when i cal forever monitor i becoming the error 'Not a Meteor app directory', from the app that i will start.

```js
var runCell = new (forever.Monitor)('main.js', {
    'max':3,
    'silent':true,
    'sourceDir':'/path/to/main.js',
    'env':{
        'ROOT_URL':'http://127.0.0.1',
        'MONGO_URL':'mongodb://xyz.com',
        'PORT':4000
    }
});

runCell.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log(code);
});

runCell.on('stdout', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

runCell.on('stderr', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

runCell.start();
```

how can i fix this?

thank's for help

Comment: please check that this wasn't just a typo. I edited your answer to format it right and noticed that there was a missing quotation mark for the `sourceDir` value. If this was literally copy&paste from your code then that could be the only problem.

Comment: thanks for answer, but a typo error can not be, the error "Error: Not a Meteor app directory" come from meteor him self. But i check my code, `'sourceDir': '/Users/username/app/installed-apps/' + app + '/bundle',`